# How do I do a bulk insert in mySQL using node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js

How would one do a bulk insert into mySQL if using something like 
https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql

Comment: what is your problem? Can you do it the same way as with one sql command? Just start next command when previous completed until you inserted all data.

Comment: I was under the impression that BULK Inserts are faster than many single inserts.

Comment: on wire level they a the same. There is no 'bulk insert' in mysql protocol

Comment: there is insert multiple in mySQL, you simply use the VALUES keyword. 

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html
INSERT statements that use VALUES syntax can insert multiple rows. To do this, include multiple lists of column values, each enclosed within parentheses and separated by commas. Example:

INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);

Answer (score 400, accepted):

Bulk inserts are possible by using nested array, see the [github page](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#escaping-query-values)

> Nested arrays are turned into grouped lists (for bulk inserts), e.g.
>   `[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]` turns into `('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd')`

You just insert a nested array of elements.

An example is given in [here](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/pull/230)

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var conn = mysql.createConnection({
    ...
});

var sql = "INSERT INTO Test (name, email, n) VALUES ?";
var values = [
    ['demian', 'demian@gmail.com', 1],
    ['john', 'john@gmail.com', 2],
    ['mark', 'mark@gmail.com', 3],
    ['pete', 'pete@gmail.com', 4]
];
conn.query(sql, [values], function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    conn.end();
});
```

*Note: `values` is an array of arrays wrapped in an array*

```
[ [ [...], [...], [...] ] ]
```

There is also a totally different [node-msql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-mysql) package for bulk insertion

Comment: Does this provide the same protections as doing `conn.execute()` to use prepared statements? If not, is it possible to utilize prepared statements when doing inserts? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, values are escaped with this method. I think it is the same mechanism as prepared statements, which also uses connection.escape() internally.

Comment: This is confusing to me. Why does the array have to be [[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]] and not [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']] like the documentation says?

Comment: Victorio Berra, it is because the outermost array is the one matching question marks in the statement in general, not just in insert. For example, if you had two question mark placeholders, then you would have [param1,param2]. 
Say "UPDATE Users ? WHERE ID=?",[columns,ID]
So, columns will be expanded to the first question mark and ID to the second one.

Comment: Is there a way to get all the inserted IDs?

Comment: @JoshHarington check my answer.

Comment: This does not work for me. My data array is `var split_tags = [ ["Luke"], ["John"] ];` My query comes out looking like this: `INSERT IGNORE INTO tags (name) VALUES (('Luke'), ('John'))`

Comment: Can someone please review this question in light of this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39563025/bulk-insert-mysql-but-from-arrays-of-objects

Comment: Unfortunately this answer is not working for me. I literally copied your answer but with no success. I posted another question on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41170849/how-to-bulk-insert-in-mysql-and-node-js-using-mysljs

Comment: I second the previous 3 comments.  Not working anymore - as of date of this comment, at least.  Oh, well.

Comment: Note that a `unique` constraint or any other problem with one record will cause the whole query to fail to insert any rows.

Comment: > Note: values is an array of arrays wrapped in an array

You're my hero ! That's the part I was missing !

Comment: Does anyone know how this would handle timestamps?

Comment: How to bulk insert when two question mark placeholders? `INSERT INTO Test (ID, LIST) VALUES ? ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE LIST = ?`

Comment: @Niska per documentation, it looks like [[[],[]], [here is second question mark item]]

Comment: On the MySQL side, a batch insert of 100 rows is about 10 times as fast as 100 single-row inserts.

Comment: I have a similar problem where I have to insert bulk records but encrypted email is stored in the DB using `AES_ENCRYPT`. `INSERT INTO Test (name, email, n) VALUES ('User1', AES_ENCRYPT('user1@email.com', saltKey), 1), ('User2', AES_ENCRYPT('user2@email.com', saltKey), 2);`
Any solution for this?

Comment: I also have a similar problem, asked in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70358386/how-can-i-insert-multiple-times-data-in-sql-server-by-running-the-inserting-func) but bulk is not working for me

Comment: As i sidenote: this was giving me a ER_WRONG_VALUE_COUNT_ON_ROW, turns out that in my query i was putting values (?) instead of values ?

Comment: worked for me with package mysql, write ? instead of (?)

Comment: Is this broken or something? It simply does not work for me.

Answer (score 35):

I ran into this today ([mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) 2.16.0) and thought I'd share my solution:

```
const items = [
    {name: 'alpha', description: 'describes alpha', value: 1},
    ...
];

db.query(
    'INSERT INTO my_table (name, description, value) VALUES ?',
    [items.map(item => [item.name, item.description, item.value])],
    (error, results) => {...}
);
```

Comment: I like your solution

Comment: This solution worked for me! TY! POSTMAN: [
{
     "textQuestionBuilderID": "5",
     "candidateID": "ABC123",
     "resultSelected": "sfgh"
 }
,
 {
     "textQuestionBuilderID": "6",
     "candidateID": "ABC123",
     "resultSelected": "sfgh"
 }
 ,
 {
     "textQuestionBuilderID": "7",
     "candidateID": "ABC123",
     "resultSelected": "sfgh"
 }
 ,
 {
     "textQuestionBuilderID": "8",
     "candidateID": "ABC123",
     "resultSelected": "sfgh"
 }
 ]

Comment: Hello!
I am also using `mysql2` and trying to do a bulk insertion but it throws me a `500`.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67672322/bulk-insert-with-mysql2-and-nodejs-throws-500 <- this is my error, is there something different than your answer? Thank you

Answer (score 29):

@Ragnar123 answer is correct, but I see a lot of people saying in the comments that it is not working. I had the same problem and it seems like you need to wrap your array in `[]` like this:

```
var pars = [
    [99, "1984-11-20", 1.1, 2.2, 200], 
    [98, "1984-11-20", 1.1, 2.2, 200], 
    [97, "1984-11-20", 1.1, 2.2, 200]
];
```

It needs to be passed like `[pars]` into the method.

Comment: Yeah, for some reason it needs to be an array, of an array of arrays...

Comment: Also looks like it requires a singular `?` instead of `??` to get the correct grouping.

Comment: It is only inserting the first record and not the rest...

Answer (score 21):

I was looking around for an answer on bulk inserting Objects.

The answer by Ragnar123 led me to making this function:

```
function bulkInsert(connection, table, objectArray, callback) {
  let keys = Object.keys(objectArray[0]);
  let values = objectArray.map( obj => keys.map( key => obj[key]));
  let sql = 'INSERT INTO ' + table + ' (' + keys.join(',') + ') VALUES ?';
  connection.query(sql, [values], function (error, results, fields) {
    if (error) callback(error);
    callback(null, results);
  });
}

bulkInsert(connection, 'my_table_of_objects', objectArray, (error, response) => {
  if (error) res.send(error);
  res.json(response);
});
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 9):

All props to Ragnar123 for his answer.

I just wanted to expand it after the question asked by Josh Harington to talk about inserted IDs.

These will be sequential.  See this answer : [Does a MySQL multi-row insert grab sequential autoincrement IDs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481421/does-a-mysql-multi-row-insert-grab-sequential-autoincrement-ids)

Hence you can just do this (notice what I did with the result.insertId):

```
  var statement = 'INSERT INTO ?? (' + sKeys.join() + ') VALUES ?';
  var insertStatement = [tableName, values];
  var sql = db.connection.format(statement, insertStatement);
  db.connection.query(sql, function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
      return clb(err);
    }
    var rowIds = [];
    for (var i = result.insertId; i < result.insertId + result.affectedRows; i++) {
      rowIds.push(i);
    }
    for (var i in persistentObjects) {
      var persistentObject = persistentObjects[i];
      persistentObject[persistentObject.idAttributeName()] = rowIds[i];
    }
    clb(null, persistentObjects);
  });
```

(I pulled the values from an array of objects that I called persistentObjects.)

Hope this helps.

Comment: are we guaranteed that in the case of simultaneous inserts the race condition wont mix insert ids?

Comment: @Purefan According to my tests yes, however who knows if this will ever change.

Comment: Note, that this will only work if the auto_increment step size is on its original value of 1. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-master.html#sysvar_auto_increment_increment

Answer (score 9):

This is a fast "raw-copy-paste" snipped to push a file column in mysql with node.js >= 11

250k row in few seconds

```
'use strict';

const mysql = require('promise-mysql');
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');

async function run() {
  const connection = await mysql.createConnection({
    host: '1.2.3.4',
    port: 3306,
    user: 'my-user',
    password: 'my-psw',
    database: 'my-db',
  });

  const rl = readline.createInterface({ input: fs.createReadStream('myfile.txt') });

  let total = 0;
  let buff = [];
  for await (const line of rl) {
    buff.push([line]);
    total++;
    if (buff.length % 2000 === 0) {
      await connection.query('INSERT INTO Phone (Number) VALUES ?', [buff]);
      console.log(total);
      buff = [];
    }
  }

  if (buff.length > 0) {
    await connection.query('INSERT INTO Phone (Number) VALUES ?', [buff]);
    console.log(total);
  }

  console.log('end');
  connection.close();
}

run().catch(console.log);
```

Comment: This works amazingly well, thank you! Note to adapters: even if you have multiple columns in INSERT, the key is to keep this single `?` after `VALUES`, without any brackets. This way array of arrays of columns can be automatically processed in bulk inserts. Used it to analyze hundreds of megabytes of access logs in MySQL.

Comment: I didn't realize why you were breaking this up into chunks until I tried it without. At some point my insert got too big for the server to process in a timely fashion and I got an EPIPE error. Breaking the insert up into chunks fixes that. :)

Answer (score 4):

If `Ragnar`'s answer doesn't work for you. Here is probably why (based on my experience) -

1. I wasn't using `node-mysql` package as shown my `Ragnar`. I was using `mysql` package. They're different (if you didn't notice - just like me). But I'm not sure if it has anything to do with the `?` not working, since it seemed to work for many folks using the `mysql` package.
2. Try using a variable instead of `?`

The following worked for me -

```
var mysql = require('node-mysql');
var conn = mysql.createConnection({
    ...
});

var sql = "INSERT INTO Test (name, email, n) VALUES :params";
var values = [
    ['demian', 'demian@gmail.com', 1],
    ['john', 'john@gmail.com', 2],
    ['mark', 'mark@gmail.com', 3],
    ['pete', 'pete@gmail.com', 4]
];
conn.query(sql, { params: values}, function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    conn.end();
});
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: I think you might forget to put the [] to values. It happened to me too.

It should be: conn.query(sql, [values], function(){})
Instead of: conn.query(sql, values, function(){})

Despite that the values variable is an array, but we still have to wrap it with []

Comment: The current node-mysql package has totally different syntax compared to mysql package. node-mysql package link is https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-mysql mysql package link is https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#escaping-query-values

Answer (score 4):

In case that needed here is how we solved insert of array

request is from postman (You will look at "guests" )

```
 {
  "author_id" : 3,
  "name" : "World War II",
  "date" : "01 09 1939", 
  "time" : "16 : 22",
  "location" : "39.9333635/32.8597419",
  "guests" : [2, 3, 1337, 1942, 1453]
}
```

And how we scripted

```
var express = require('express');
var utils = require('./custom_utils.js');

module.exports = function(database){
    var router = express.Router();

    router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
        database.query('INSERT INTO activity (author_id, name, date, time, location) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name = VALUES(name), date = VALUES(date), time = VALUES(time), location = VALUES(location)', 
                [req.body.author_id, req.body.name, req.body.date, req.body.time, req.body.location], function(err, results, fields){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
                res.json({ status: utils.respondMSG.DB_ERROR });
            }
            else {
                var act_id = results.insertId;
                database.query('INSERT INTO act_guest (user_id, activity_id, status) VALUES ? ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE status = VALUES(status)', 
                        [Array.from(req.body.guests).map(function(g){ return [g, act_id, 0]; })], function(err, results, fields){
                    if(err){
                        console.log(err);
                        res.json({ status: utils.respondMSG.DB_ERROR });
                    }
                    else {
                        res.json({ 
                            status: utils.respondMSG.SUCCEED,
                            data: {
                                activity_id : act_id
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
    return router;
};
```

Answer (score 4):

I was having similar problem. It was just inserting one from the list of arrays. It worked after making the below changes.

1. Passed [params] to the query method.
2. Changed the query from insert (a,b) into table1 values (?) ==> insert (a,b) into table1 values ? . ie. Removed the paranthesis around the question mark.

Hope this helps. I am using mysql npm.

Answer (score 3):

Few things I want to mention is that I'm using [mysql](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql) package for making a connection with my database and what you saw below is working code and written for insert bulk query.

```
const values = [
  [1, 'DEBUG', 'Something went wrong. I have to debug this.'],
  [2, 'INFO', 'This just information to end user.'],
  [3, 'WARNING', 'Warning are really helping users.'],
  [4, 'SUCCESS', 'If everything works then your request is successful']
];

const query = "INSERT INTO logs(id, type, desc) VALUES ?";

const query = connection.query(query, [values], function(err, result) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('err', err)
  }

  console.log('result', result)
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Bulk insert in Node.js can be done using the below code. I have referred lots of blog for getting this work.

please refer this link as well.
https://www.technicalkeeda.com/nodejs-tutorials/insert-multiple-records-into-mysql-using-nodejs

The working code.

```
  const educations = request.body.educations;
  let queryParams = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < educations.length; i++) {
    const education = educations[i];
    const userId = education.user_id;
    const from = education.from;
    const to = education.to;
    const instituteName = education.institute_name;
    const city = education.city;
    const country = education.country;
    const certificateType = education.certificate_type;
    const studyField = education.study_field;
    const duration = education.duration;

    let param = [
      from,
      to,
      instituteName,
      city,
      country,
      certificateType,
      studyField,
      duration,
      userId,
    ];

    queryParams.push(param);
  }

  let sql =
    "insert into tbl_name (education_from, education_to, education_institute_name, education_city, education_country, education_certificate_type, education_study_field, education_duration, user_id) VALUES ?";
  let sqlQuery = dbManager.query(sql, [queryParams], function (
    err,
    results,
    fields
  ) {
    let res;
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res = {
        success: false,
        message: "Insertion failed!",
      };
    } else {
      res = {
        success: true,
        id: results.insertId,
        message: "Successfully inserted",
      };
    }

    response.send(res);
  });
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert object, use this:

```
    currentLogs = [
 { socket_id: 'Server', message: 'Socketio online', data: 'Port  3333', logged: '2014-05-14 14:41:11' },
 { socket_id: 'Server', message: 'Waiting for Pi to connect...', data: 'Port: 8082', logged: '2014-05-14 14:41:11' }
];

console.warn(currentLogs.map(logs=>[ logs.socket_id , logs.message , logs.data , logs.logged ]));
```

The output will be:

```
[
  [ 'Server', 'Socketio online', 'Port  3333', '2014-05-14 14:41:11' ],
  [
    'Server',
    'Waiting for Pi to connect...',
    'Port: 8082',
    '2014-05-14 14:41:11'
  ]
]
```

Also, please check the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to know more about the map function.

Answer (score 0):

```
Client.createClient = (clientReqData, result) =>{
var command = 'INSERT INTO client (name,email,phone,country_code,city,state,address,salaes_account_manager,internal_notes) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)' ;
dbConn.query(command,[clientReqData.name,
    clientReqData.email,clientReqData.phone,clientReqData.country_code,clientReqData.city,clientReqData.state,clientReqData.address,clientReqData.salaes_account_manager,clientReqData.internal_notes],(err,res)=>{
    if(err){
        console.log(err)
    }else {
        client_id = res.insertId;
        var command = 'INSERT INTO client_contact_person (name, email ,phone,client_id) VALUES ?';
        dbConn.query(command,
            [clientReqData.contact.map(item => [item.name, item.email, item.phone,client_id])],
            (err, res) => {
                if(err) throw err
            }
        );
        result(null,res);
    }
})
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I propose you to use this library specialized in MySQL. Its use is very simple.

```js
npm i object_mysql
```

This would be an example based on the response of January 22, 2015 at 9:39 p.m.

```
import db from 'object_mysql';

const { Test } = await db();

const values = [
    { name:'demian', email:'demian@gmail.com', n:1 },
    { name:'john', email:'john@gmail.com', n:2 },
    { name:'mark', email:'mark@gmail.com', n:3 },
    { name:'pete', email:'pete@gmail.com', n:4 }
];

await Test.add(values);
```