# Node Mysql is breaking node app entirely

Tags: mysql, node.js, npm

For some reason, my node app (specifically the node module) is getting a "Too many connections" error that I can't figure out what is actually causing it, but rather than handling the error it's completely crashing the app.

To give you an idea of what this looks like:

```
/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:52
  var err  = new Error(code + ': ' + packet.message);
             ^
Error: ER_CON_COUNT_ERROR: Too many connections
```

What is the best way to handle this so it is not actually killing the app?

This is when running npm run dev.

Comment: Hard to tell... you need to give more code...

Comment: The error is pain fully obvious what your doing. Your not closing or reusing the database connections and are opening new ones every time.

Comment: `but rather than handling the error it's completely crashing the app.` It's crashing the app because **you** are not handling the error. I recommend using a connection pool.

Comment: Somewhere in your code you are not closing your connections and or not using a connection pool. Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27746512/er-con-count-error-too-many-connections-error-in-node-mysql?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ER\_CON\_COUNT\_ERROR: Too many connections error in node-mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27746512/er-con-count-error-too-many-connections-error-in-node-mysql)

Answer (score -1):

I solved an issue related to this using

```
try{

}
catch (e){

}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).