# Unable to send JSON data from Express node Js to MYSQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

Can you please tell me how to send a JSON Data from Express Js to MY Sql using Node Js.

```
myObj= [{'name':'name1'},{'name':'name1'},{'name':'name1'}, {'name':'name1'}];

connection.query('INSERT INTO myTable SET ?', myObj, function(err,  result)
{
   console.log(result);
});
```

In my table **myTable**
I have done is `create table mytable(jsonData LONGTEXT);`

Comment: Can you please help me out..

Comment: You use json vector, see if would can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899802/how-do-i-do-a-bulk-insert-in-mysql-using-node-js