# NodeJS insert bulk values into MySQL

Tags: mysql

I want to do a bulk insert to MYSQL table. According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899802/how-do-i-do-a-bulk-insert-in-mysql-using-node-js), I'm using a 2D array. However, I kept getting MYSQL Syntax errors. Can anyone point me out?

Error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL'
```

I have five columns in db, which has an auto-incrementing `Id` , `update_date` and `create_date` which I didn't put in the `insert` query. For `update_date` and `create_date` I set it to `on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

```
var insert = 'INSERT INTO table2 (link, text) VALUES ?';
var res = [['www.google.com', 'google'],['www.bing.com', 'bing']];
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'XXX',
    database: 'dbname'
});
connection.connect();
connection.query(insert, [res], function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err)
        connection.end();
        throw err;
    }
    connection.end();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the 'default' missing from your field definition ?

```
    update_date timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Comment: Can you insert a record manually? ie. in mysql console or WorkBench run INSERT INTO table2 (link,text) VALUES ('www.google.com','google');

Comment: Yes I could insert manually. but the date values are null. I need to alter the table to set the default value not null. However, this didn't solve my problem.;-(

Comment: So, you haven't altered the table definition?

Comment: `alter table table2 modify created_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` I altered it already.

Comment: `6 apple.com 2016-01-19 09:21:51 2016-01-19 09:21:51 apple` - sample record inserted manually

Comment: Probably good to run it while monitoring using Workbench - Management - Client Connections to see what the insert query looks like.