# INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE multiple rows at once

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, insert-update

I'm using node.js and mysql. I'm trying to insert multiple rows with one query, and if the rows with that primary key already exist, update it.

PK is `exchange + currency1 + currency2`.

But only one row gets inserted (instead of five).

Here is my `valuesArray`:

```
  [ [ 4, 'BTC', 'IDR', 10440000, 10391000 ],
  [ 4, 'BTC', 'MYR', 2380, 2095 ],
  [ 4, 'BTC', 'ZAR', 11216, 11201 ],
  [ 4, 'BTC', 'SGD', 1100, 1093 ],
  [ 4, 'BTC', 'NGN', 403500, 402701 ] ]
```

and here is my query:

```
connection.query("INSERT INTO rates (exchange,currency1,currency2,buyrate,sellrate) VALUES(?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE buyrate=VALUES(buyrate), sellrate=VALUES(sellrate)", valuesArray, function (err) {
    });
```

I've tried changing my query to this (just adding [ ] around valuesArray):

```
connection.query("INSERT INTO rates (exchange,currency1,currency2,buyrate,sellrate) VALUES(?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE buyrate=VALUES(buyrate), sellrate=VALUES(sellrate)", [valuesArray], function (err) {
        });
```

but then I get this error:

```
{ [Error: ER_OPERAND_COLUMNS: Operand should contain 1 column(s)]
  code: 'ER_OPERAND_COLUMNS',
  errno: 1241,
  sqlState: '21000',
  index: 0 }
```

Comment: Which row gets inserted?

Comment: @Kryten the first one

Comment: Use `...VALUES ? ON DUPLICATE...` (without brackets) and `[valuesArray]` (with brackets).

Comment: Use **VALUES ?** instead of **VALUES(?)** and see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899802/how-do-i-do-a-bulk-insert-in-mysql-using-node-js

Comment: @BerndBuffen yes I saw that question before I posted mine, but it didn't help me. Solarflare solved my problem. I just don't know how to promote his answer to be accepted answer for this question. Thanks for your effort anyway!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad/3653574

Comment: @Solarflare please answer this question with your answer from comment so I can mark it as correct and close the question topic.

Comment: @kecman This was just a pointer to the correct syntax (which I was sure someone else asked before, so I didn't post it as an answer). Glad it helped, but my answer would look nearly word for word like the one Bernd linked. This is actually a duplicate (and should be deleted); since you saw it before and it didn't help, that might be true for someone else and he might find your question more helpful, so feel free to self-answer with the solution (that would have helped you more than the other answer). Might still get flagged (and deleted) as a duplicate though. Or delete it yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> answer by @Solarflare:

Use `...VALUES ? ON DUPLICATE...` (without brackets) and `[valuesArray]` (with brackets).