# How to bulk insert in mySql and node.js using mysljs

Tags: mysql, node.js, bluebird

Im not able to use bulk insert in my DB using node.js lib [mysljs](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql).

I followed answers from:

[How do I do a bulk insert in mySQL using node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899802/how-do-i-do-a-bulk-insert-in-mysql-using-node-js)

with no success.

```
var sql = "INSERT INTO resources (resource_container_id, name, title, extension, mime_type, size) VALUES ?";

var values = [
  [1, 'pic1', 'title1', '.png', 'image/png', 500], 
  [1, 'pic2', 'title2', '.png', 'image/png', 700]];

return connection.query(sql, [values], (result) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    connection.end();
});
```

I keep getting error:

```
 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near \'?\' at line 1'
```

I also tried to promisify the query mehod using bluebird but with no success, I get same error again.

Comment: typo in the callback there should be `(err, result)=>{...}` but that is likely not the error you describe here, since the err is actualy printed at some point so i assume that it's just a copy error.

Answer (score 1):

You need to mark your keys with the grave accent (backtick) character, like this: `key`

Making your `query` like this:

```
var sql = "INSERT INTO resources (`resource_container_id`, `name`, `title`, `extension`, `mime_type`, `size`) VALUES ?";
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me, still get the error.

Answer (score 1):

try using () around the question mark

`var sql = "INSERT INTO resources (resource_container_id, name, title, extension, mime_type, size) VALUES (?) ";`

Comment: I have the same issue with mysql2 library and also doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue only when i use `connection.execute()` and then it's actually because it is not implemented for prepared statements.

I resolved the issue by using `connection.query()` instead.

Don't know if that answer helps anyone tho.

It would help me when I was searching for the answer.

Answer (score -2):

Try removing the square brackets around `values`

Comment: square brackets around `values` imply array