# How to insert json output into mysql with node js

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, node.js

```
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app     = express();

var output;
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.get('/scrape', function(req, res){
    url = 'https://raitalumni.dypatil.edu/events/?tag=live';

    request(url, function(error, response, html){
        if(!error){
            var $ = cheerio.load(html);
            var json = {
                            title : [],
                            date  : [],
                            month : [],
                            venue : [],
                            link : []
                       };
             output = {
                            events : []
                         };

            $('p.event_name').each(function(){
                json.title.push($(this).text());
            });




            $('p.calendar_date').each(function(){
                json.date.push($(this).text());
            });

            $('span.calendar_month').each(function(){
                json.month.push($(this).text());
            });


            //var fulldate = $('p.calendar_date').concat($('p.calendar_day')).text();
            //console.log('all records: ' + fulldate);

            $('p.event_venue').each(function(){
                json.venue.push($(this).text());
            });

        // var title = $('p.event_name').each(function(){$(this).text()});



            for(var i=0; i<json.title.length; i++){
                output.events[i] = {
                    title : json.title[i],
                    date : json.date[i],
                    month : json.month[i],
                    venue : json.venue[i],
                    link : url
                }
            }

         var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: '127.0.0.1',
        port: 3306,
        user: 'root',
        password: '',
        database: 'raithub'
    });


connection.connect(function(error){
   if(!!error){
      console.log('Error');
   }else{
      console.log('Connected to the database!');
   }
});



       var scrape = JSON.stringify(output, null, 4);
       console.log(scrape);

       var query = connection.query("INSERT INTO scrapped ('title','date','month','venue','link') VALUES ('" + output.title + "', '" + output.date + "', '" + output.month + "', '" + output.venue + "', '" + output.link + "');", scrape, function(err, result) {
     if(err) throw err;
     console.log('data inserted');
});


            fs.writeFile('output4.json', JSON.stringify(output, null, 4), function(err){
                console.log('File successfully written! - Check your project directory for the output.json file');
            })

            res.send('Check your console!')         
        }
        else {
            console.log("Network Error, please try again later")
        }
    })
})





app.listen('8000')
console.log('Server running on port 8081');
exports = module.exports = app;
```

Where am I going wrong?

Getting this error,

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''title','date','month','venue','li
nk') VALUES ('undefined', 'undefined', 'undefi' at line 1 error
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The INSERT statement should look this:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3, ...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...);
```

where the column names should not be in quotes. Your specific statement would like this:

```
    var query = connection.query("INSERT INTO scrapped (title,date,month,venue,link) VALUES ('" + output.title + "', '" + output.date + "', '" + output.month + "', '" + output.venue + "', '" + output.link + "');", scrape, function(err, result) {
     if(err) throw err;
     console.log('data inserted');
});
```

See [this](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp) for the right syntax

Comment: This worked. thanks. but when I checked the database I'm getting 'undefined' value for all rows.

Comment: Any idea why this happened? Also only one row is updated when there are two records in output.

Comment: Thats probably because output.title is not a property. instead output.event[i].title might be because it looks like output has an array property called event and each of those has title etc property. And your query only does one query. You need to use a for loop to create a bigger query and that goes over all the elements in the output.events array

Comment: What should be the correct syntax? I want to use title, date etc to insert into different cols in mysql?

Comment: Can you suggest how to code that? I'm new to node.js

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899802/how-do-i-do-a-bulk-insert-in-mysql-using-node-js

Comment: this way of JSON inserting you have to escape it manually by  `connection.escape`

Answer (score 1):

There is a JSON datatype in MySQL.

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE t1 (jdoc JSON);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.20 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO t1 VALUES('{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
```

This would be especially helpful if you had a very large json object and didn't want to create a huge INSERT statement. It would also be useful if you are unsure of the exact data that will be coming in via json but you want to capture all of it. I'm currently working on a project where we occasionally add and remove items from the user input fields and this is very helpful so that I'm not constantly having to ALTER tables and edit other statements in MySQL.

More information can be found here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html

Answer (score 1):

```
const queryString = `insert into table_name(meta_column) values ('${JSON.stringify(meta)}');`;
```

Where `meta` is a JSON object, we need to convert it to a JSON tring by using `JSON.stringify` first then insert the value as JSON string.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.