# How do I use expression with bulk insert using npm mysql?

Tags: mysql, node.js

This question answers 99% of what I am looking for...
[How do I do a bulk insert in mySQL using node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899802/how-do-i-do-a-bulk-insert-in-mysql-using-node-js)

```
var sql = "INSERT INTO Test (name, email, n) VALUES ?";
var values = [
    ['demian', 'demian@gmail.com', 1],
    ['john', 'john@gmail.com', 2],
    ['mark', 'mark@gmail.com', 3],
    ['pete', 'pete@gmail.com', 4]
];
conn.query(sql, [values], function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    conn.end();
});
```

If I want to pass an expression, such as `NOW()`, how would I do that? If I pass it in the array, it would count as a string. Since `VALUES` is a `?` that gets populated by the array, I can't easily inject an expression. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically it seems impossible, so you should make a query string you want.

I would try this as follows.

```
var sql = "INSERT INTO Test (name, email, n, modified_on) VALUES ?";
var values = [
    ['demian', 'demian@gmail.com', 1, '::NOW()'],
    ['john', 'john@gmail.com', 2, '::UNIX_TIMESTAMP()'],
    ['mark', 'mark@gmail.com', 3, '::DATE()'],
    ['pete', 'pete@gmail.com', 4, '::NOW()']
];

var formattedQuery = connection.format(sql, [values]).replace(/'::(.*?)'/g, '$1');

connection.query(formattedQuery, function(err) {
});
```

`fomattedQuery` is as follows.

```
INSERT INTO Test (name, email, n, modified_on) VALUES ('demian', 'demian@gmail.com', 1, NOW()), ('john', 'john@gmail.com', 2, UNIX_TIMESTAMP()), ('mark', 'mark@gmail.com', 3, DATE()), ('pete', 'pete@gmail.com', 4, NOW())
```

I hope this helps.