# how to bulk insert using mysql node module with a subquery

Tags: mysql, node.js

I had reviewed [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899802/how-do-i-do-a-bulk-insert-in-mysql-using-node-js) which covers performing a bulk insert using the mysql node module but with a very particular syntax that doesn't include the use of subqueries.  I was wondering how I would perform a bulk insert using this module for a query like this.

```
db.query('insert into pizzas (qty, timeDayCityId) values (?, (select id from timeDayCity where time_id = ? and day_id = ? and city_id = ?)', [qty, time_id, day_id, city_id])
```

While I'm able to run this in the mysql module just fine over a loop, I was hoping for a speedier insert process, but can't seem to figure out how to adjust the syntax so it works for a bulk insert operation.  Cheers.

Comment: I don't even see how this is a bulk insert.  Are you saying you have some loop which would change the values of the parameters?

Comment: while the loop itself doesn't change the paramters per iteration, yes, the parameters do change per iteration as I'm parsing data I received from an API call and then performing an insert operation.  I'd prefer to work with a bulk insert over performing a bunch of separate insert operations over a loop.  Thanks.

Comment: I don't see a nice way of doing this, so +1.  See if you can somehow reduce the query to a simple `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`.

Comment: I am also trying to solve the same problem. Any luck?