# Node mysql bulk insert with express array parameter

Tags: mysql, arrays, node.js

I've come across a situation where I need to use a bulk insert with my Node project.

This of course has already been answered here: [How do I do a bulk insert in mySQL using node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899802/how-do-i-do-a-bulk-insert-in-mysql-using-node-js)

However, I have an express project which I use to create an api. The parameters are turned into an array and I'm having trouble using that array with a bulk insert. Whenever I try to use that route, I get an error of `Error: ER_WRONG_VALUE_COUNT_ON_ROW: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1`

After some digging I found that it tries to insert:

```
['foo', 'bar', 'test']
```

When I need it to insert:

```
['foo']
['bar']
['test']
```

Anyways, here's the whole code:

### Route

```
router.post("/", function (req, res, next) {
    db.query(
        "REPLACE INTO user (`Name`) VALUES (?)",
        [req.query.array],
        function (error, response) {
            if (error) throw error;

            console.log(response);
         }
    )
});
```

### Route Caller

```
let requestUrl = "http://localhost:3000/user?";

// External api request which returns a list of users
for (let i = 0; i < body.users.length; i++) {
    requestUrl += `array=${body.users[i]}&`
}

let addUserRequest = {
    url: requestUrl,
    method: "POST"
};

request(addUserRequest, function (error, response, body) {
    console.log(body);
});
```

The url that is generated is:

```
http://localhost:3000/user?array=foo&array=bar&array=test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
var datatoDB = [];
req.query.array.forEach(function(entry) {
    console.log(entry);
    datatoDB.push([entry]);
});
```

Here we are trying to convert this `['foo', 'bar', 'test']` to this `[["foo"], ["bar"], ["test"]]`. 
Now, use datatoDB in your function.

```
router.post("/", function (req, res, next) {
    db.query(
        "REPLACE INTO user (Name) VALUES ?", 
        [datatoDB],
        function (error, response) {
            if (error) throw error;

            console.log(response);
         }
    )
});
```

Comment: So your method is closer, it inserts the first value and then finishes. I then took another look back at the answer I mentioned in my post and wrapped it in another array like `[datatoDB]` but that returned the same column count error.

Comment: It seems my sql syntax was wrong and I did need that extra set of brackets.

If you could change your answer so that the query reads `REPLACE INTO user (Name) VALUES ?, [datatoDB]` I will gladly accept it so that it helps others with this similar issue.