# Troubles while trying to bulk insert an array of users in Node

Tags: mysql, node.js, npm

I've been spending a lot of time looking at all the solutions provided on how to do a bulk insert with Node (notably [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899802/how-do-i-do-a-bulk-insert-in-mysql-using-node-js), [here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-nodejs/insert/) and [here](http://www.technicalkeeda.com/nodejs-tutorials/insert-multiple-records-into-mysql-using-nodejs)), but I'm still not able to insert multiple rows from a list of users.

My array looks like this:

```
[ [ 'user 1' ], [ 'user 2' ], [ 'user3' ] ]
```

And my code is the following:

```
let insert_sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO followers (username) VALUES (?)"
  await connection.execute(insert_sql, [users], function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err
    console.log("Number of records inserted: " + result.affectedRows)
  })
```

But it only inserts all the users in one row...
I'm using npm and mysql2 package, may this be the problem's origin?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change to `.query()` so it's building longer query on the client side or use .execute and serialise your insert data to/from single parameter ( for example, using JSON field and stored procedure ) or use matching number of placeholders in query text `let insert_sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO followers (username) VALUES (?, ?, ?)"; await connection.execute(insert_sql, [users])`.

Here is my [answer](https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2/issues/476#issuecomment-264342349) to explain difference between execute vs query to "why IN ? does not wark with execute?" question:

> .execute() under the hood is doing prepare + execute commands
>
> query vs execute step by step:
>
> query:
>
> format sql on the client: 'SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE id IN (?)' + [
>   [1,2,3] ] becomes 'SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3)' send
>   COM_QUERY command with 'SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3)'
>   read fields + rows execute:
>
> send COM_PREPARE command with SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE id IN (?)
>   as query parameter read prepared statement result (id + parameters +
>   result fields if known from query ). For this query there is one
>   parameter ( one ? ). id is a number, usually starts with 1 for every
>   connection ( not unique server-wise, you can't prepare statement in
>   one connection and use in another ) send COM_EXECUTE command using
>   statement id + parameters. Parameters must be simple mysql types, and
>   currently all parameters coerced to strings and serialised as strings
>   (with exception for Buffer parameters, they sent as is). In your
>   example is "please execute stmt with id 1 and one parameter which is a
>   string "1,2,3" Result from prepare step above is cached, with next
>   execute commands with same query only 'COM_EXECUTE' part is performed
>
> I agree that this is confusing but this is how prepared statement
>   work. We should improve this with better documentation and maybe some
>   parameter validation warnings/errors like _"hey, are you sure you want
>   to send your {foo: 'bar'} parameter to prepared statement? It'll be
>   sent as [Object object]!''