# How to use LAST_INSERT_ID() to INSERT multiple records with the same value

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, many-to-many

So most questions about `LAST_INSERT_ID()` with multiple `INSERT` records involve getting multiple IDs back after the insert, my question is backwards from that.

I have table `foo`, with a many-to-many relationship with `bar`, and a junction table, `foo__bar`. I want to `INSERT` a single `foo` record, but also an unknown quantity of `bar` associations, so I need the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` after the first `INSERT` statement, but multiple times:

```
const db = require('mysql');
...
//connection and pooling set up

let sql = `INSERT INTO foo VALUES(null, ?, ?);
           INSERT INTO foo__bar((LAST_INSERT_ID(), ?), (LAST_INSERT_ID(), ?)//etc
          `;
let barIds = [1,4];

let params = [name, description, barIds[0], barIds[1]];

let result = await db.query(sql, params);
```

This works fine if the `bar` table is already populated and the `bar` ids are valid, and I only ever do two associations per `INSERT`:

```
--table foo__bar

+------+------+
|foo_id|bar_id|
|------|------|
|     1|     1|
|------|------|
|     1|     4|
+------+------+
```

But what if I have multiple values/associations? Using the 'mysql' npm package, normally I could just do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899802/how-do-i-do-a-bulk-insert-in-mysql-using-node-js) and an array will be converted into `((val1, val2),(val1, val2),(val1,val1))` etc. However, for my junction table, I need `val1` to be the same every time, specifically `LAST_INSERT_ID()`. Is this possible without having to make two async calls to the database?

Thanks

Comment: So someone elsewhere mentioned the only way to do this is with two separate queries, using transactions to make sure there aren't any widow/orphans. Anyone have insights?

Comment: Yes, my understanding is also that you would need a transaction to do this.