# Should I insert an object with arrays as properties in a for-loop into my database?

Tags: mysql, arrays, angular, express, mean-stack

I am new to MySQL and I wonder how to approach the following proplem.
I have an object with:

```
{
  id: number,
  names: [string]
}
```

If I wanted to insert this object, would I have to insert it in a for loop, since arrays should not be stored in one single cell?

```
for(let i=0; obj.names.length > i; i++){
  this.service.postObj({id: obj.id, names: obj.names[i]});
}
```

Would it be the right way?
If so, what if I had to iterate through all properties representing an array? As far as I know now, I would have to do it like above but it is really inefficient. Do I oversee something?

I use the MEAN stack (here MySQL, Express, Angular and Nodejs).

Comment: Maybe this link may be helpful: [how-do-i-do-a-bulk-insert-in-mysql-using-node-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899802/how-do-i-do-a-bulk-insert-in-mysql-using-node-js)

Comment: Thank you for helping me! I will read it!

Answer (score 1):

Either:

- Add a row for each item in the array. This would mean each item gets a unique ID
- Create another table with a many-to-one relation