# Bulk Insert into Mysql from Object Array NodeJS

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I'm not sure what I'm missing, I thought putting Games in brackets would let me do bulk insert to MySQL. However when I do this it comes back as (OBJECT,OBJECT). If I remove the brackets then I only get one single insert but it works! Any suggestions to do bulk insert?

**Short sample of the Array**

```
[{title:xxx,link:https://xxxx,description:xxx.,xxx:xxxxx},{title:xxx,link:https://xxxx,description:xxx.,xxx:xxxxx}]
```

**Javascript**

```
// Writing the Games inside a json file
fs.writeFile("feed.json", JSON.stringify(Games), function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Saved!");
});

 con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");
  var sqlquery  = "INSERT INTO gtable (title, link, description, company) VALUES ?";
  let queryData = {
    sql: sqlquery,
    values: [Games]
  }
  con.query(queryData, function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Number of records inserted: " + result.affectedRows);
  });
});
```

Comment: What if you try something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14259347/10431732)? So, something like: `con.query(sqlquery, [Games], function (err, result) { /* ... */ })`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your issue may be that you are passing an array of objects while MySQL is expecting an array of arrays.

Your format is basically:

```js
var sqlquery  = "INSERT INTO gtable (title, link, description, company) VALUES ?";
var values = [
[{title:xxx,link:https://xxxx,description:xxx.,xxx:xxxxx}
{title:xxx,link:https://xxxx,description:xxx.,xxx:xxxxx}]
];
```

When it should be:

```js
var sqlquery  = "INSERT INTO gtable (title, link, description, company) VALUES ?";
var values = [
[[title1,link1,description1,xxx1],
[title2,link2,description2,xxx2]]
];
```

You would need to convert each object to an array of just its values. Which you could do with something like this I think:

```js
let sqlValues = Games.map(obj => Object.values(obj));
```

EDIT: I had the incorrect format for the mapping, fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

I believe [@otw has a solid solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62706770/10431732) (and an awesome explanation of why this is happening), but to offer an alternative solution you could do something like this:

```js
Games.forEach(game => {
  con.query('INSERT INTO gtable SET ?', game, insertErr => {
    if (insertErr) {
      throw new Error("Error inserting game " + game.title + "! " + insertErr);
    }
  
    console.log(`Inserted ${game.title}!`);
  });
})
```

Comment: as an alternative solution, this works well! thanks!