# Changes in the nodejs code for inserting a batch in mySQL table

Tags: mysql, node.js

Here is the code

```
const add_friend = async (user_id, users) => {
    try {
             var data1 = [];
        for (const user of users) {
            data1 += [user,user_id,"Request Pending"];
                }
            await mysql.query('INSERT INTO friendship SET ?', [data1])
            await mysql.end()
}
     catch (err) {
        throw err
```

So users is the list of all other user_id's which is coming as a parameter.
user_id is a single id.
What I am trying is to convert it into one list data1 with three values user_id1, user_id2, and request pending after that I want to update the table in one query only.

But the syntax is not correct. What should be the correct syntax. Please help.

Comment: answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899802/how-do-i-do-a-bulk-insert-in-mysql-using-node-js

Comment: My case is a little different but abhilash. here I am already having a user list and I am converting it again. In the link they are using their own input values. That I got but here is a little bit different. if you could correct the code.

Comment: you'll need to use `data1.push([user1,...])` instead of `+=`

Comment: ok. anything other than that

Comment: query should be `VALUES ?` instead of `SET ?`. I'd encourage you to post an answer after you fix :)

Comment: ok. will do that

Comment: it is giving an error near values statement