# How to insert multiple rows with JSON data at the same time into MySQL using node.js?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, database

I want to insert multiple values into columns at the same time. For example, I have a JSON data with two rows of data, and I want to insert it at once in my table. I have tried this:

```
var data = ['{"sensorvalue":"96"},{"sensorvalue":"98"}']

const jsdata = JSON.parse(data);

connection.query("INSERT INTO `nodes`(`sensorvalue`) VALUES ('"+jsdata.sensorvalue+"')", (err, res) => {
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log("counter record inserted");  
});
```

Shows me this error:

```
{"sensorvalue":"96"},{"sensorvalue":"98"}
                    ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token , in JSON
```

The output it should be:

| id | sensorvalue |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 96 |
| 2 | 98 |

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899802/how-do-i-do-a-bulk-insert-in-mysql-using-node-js

Comment: I would expect it to be `var data = '[{"sensorvalue":"96"},{"sensorvalue":"98"}]'` what you have is an array with a single element containing two objects with a comment in between. i have a string with a json array containing two objects

Comment: @Ali I think this is different not array of arrays instead it is a JSON data.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var data = ['{"sensorvalue":"96"},{"sensorvalue":"98"}']
```

should be

```js
var data = '[{"sensorvalue":"96"},{"sensorvalue":"98"}]'
```

The top is an `array` with a single element containing two `object`s with a comma (`,`) in between. The bottom is a `string` with a json `array` containing two `object`s

Comment: Thanks. But, I'm still I can not insert it as two rows.