# How to insert values from JSON data with multiple objects into rows in MySQL?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, json

I can store a value in a JSON data with one object into MySQL data base, like this:

```
var data = '{"sensorvalue":"96"}'

const jsdata = JSON.parse(data);
connection.query("INSERT INTO `nodes`(`sensorvalue`) VALUES ('"+jsdata.sensorvalue+"')", (err, res) => {
    console.log("counter record inserted");  
});
```

The output:

| id | sensorvalue |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 96 |

However, I want to store values in a JSON data with two or more objects, like this:

```
var data = '[{"sensorvalue":"96"},{"sensorvalue":"98"}]'
```

But, it stores it as a `undefined` in row in table.

The expected output:

| id | sensorvalue |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 96 |
| 2 | 98 |

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899802/how-do-i-do-a-bulk-insert-in-mysql-using-node-js)before but I don't know how this could help me because in that question is about array of arrays not a JSON data with multiple objects.
How could I solve this, please?

Comment: In `[{"sensorvalue":"96"},{"sensorvalue":"98"}]` Do you not see an array of objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an array, you need to loop over it.

You also shouldn't substitute values directly into the SQL, use parametrized queries.

```
const jsArray = JSON.parse(data);
jsArray.forEach(jsdata =>
  connection.query("INSERT INTO `nodes`(`sensorvalue`) VALUES (?)", [jsdata.sensorvalue], (err, res) => {
    console.log("counter record inserted");
  })
);
```

The node.js MySQL connector also allows you to use a 2-dimensional array to insert values in multiple rows at once. See [How do I do a bulk insert in mySQL using node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899802/how-do-i-do-a-bulk-insert-in-mysql-using-node-js)

```
const sensorValues = JSON.parse(data).map(el => [el.sensorvalue]);
connection.query("INSERT INTO `nodes`(`sensorvalue`) VALUES ?", sensorValues, (err, res) => {
  console.log(`${sensorValues.length} counter records inserted`);
});
```