# Bulk insert with mysql2 and NodeJs throws 500

Tags: mysql, node.js, bulkinsert, node-mysql2

I have a method which I want to `bulk insert` into mysql. I am using `NodeJS` and `mysql2`.

My method:

```
createWorklog = async ({ sqlArray }) => {
        const sql = `INSERT INTO ${this.tableName}
        (project_id, user_id, date, duration, task, description) VALUES ?`

        const result = await query(sql, [sqlArray])
        const affectedRows = result ? result.affectedRows : 0;

        return affectedRows;
}
```

Where `sqlArray` is an `array of arrays` where all the children arrays are the same length.

And the `query` method that is called in this method is the next one:

```
query = async (sql, values) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const callback = (error, result) => {
        if (error) {
          reject(error);
          return;
        }
        resolve(result);
      }
      // execute will internally call prepare and query
      this.db.execute(sql, values, callback);
    }).catch(err => {
      const mysqlErrorList = Object.keys(HttpStatusCodes);
      // convert mysql errors which in the mysqlErrorList list to http status code
      err.status = mysqlErrorList.includes(err.code) ? HttpStatusCodes[err.code] : err.status;

      throw err;
    });
  }
}
```

My problem is that the `body parameters` are ok (as I said, array of arrays) but the method throws `500`.

Can this be possible because of `execute` command that is present in `mysql2`? Or is another mistake?

Thank you for your time!

**EDIT**

I changed my method from using 'execute' to 'query' Based on @Gaurav’s answer and it's working well.

Comment: 500 is an http error. It's probably generated when you do `throw err` in your nodejs code. I suggest you use `console.err(err)` to display the mysql error. Also, [npm mysql2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2) handles `await db.execute()` natively; you don't need to promisify it yourself. You can simplify your code a lot. That will help with troubleshooting.

Comment: found helpful resources here -->  https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2/issues/830

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a known issue with `execute` and `query` method in `mysql2`

I've found a working alternative.

```
createWorklog = async ({ sqlArray }) => {
        const sql = `INSERT INTO ${this.tableName}
        (project_id, user_id, date, duration, task, description) VALUES ?`

        const result = await query(sql, [sqlArray], true) // adding true for multiple insert
        const affectedRows = result ? result.affectedRows : 0;

        return affectedRows;
}
```

Then query can be written as below

```
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const callback = ...

      if (multiple) this.db.query(sql, values, callback);
            else this.db.execute(sql, values, callback);

    }).catch(err => {
      ...
...
    });
  }
}
```

More info regarding this issue can be found here https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2/issues/830

Comment: I like your idea, i changed my code from using 'execute' to 'query' and is working well, but your 'if else' is better, but i still need to research to find the performance differences between 'query' and 'execute' and maybe other details. Thank you for your time.