# How to batch insert data into MySQL in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, json, aws-lambda

I am developing a REST API. One of the end points I have recieve a list of data like below.

```
[
    {
        
        "iduser": 3,
        "title": "House in kandala",
        "description": "Built a house in kandala area"
    },
    {
        
        "iduser": 3,
        "title": "House in NYC",
        "description": "Built a house in greater NYC area"
    }
]
```

I need to save the list into the database. Below is my code.

```
const mysql = require('mysql2');
const errorCodes = require('source/error-codes');
const PropertiesReader = require('properties-reader');

const prop = PropertiesReader('properties.properties');

const con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: prop.get('server.host'),
    user: prop.get("server.username"),
    password: prop.get("server.password"),
    port: prop.get("server.port"),
    database: prop.get("server.dbname")
});


exports.saveSellerPortfolioItem = (event, context, callback) => {

    context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;

    if (event.body == null && event.body == undefined) {
        var response = errorCodes.missing_parameters;
        callback(null, response)
    }
    else {
        let body = JSON.parse(event.body)
        console.log("body", body);

        let iduser = Number(body.iduser);
        let title = body.title;
        let description = body.description;
     

        if (isNaN(iduser)) {
            var response = errorCodes.invalid_parameter;
            callback(null, response);
        }
        else {
            // allows for using callbacks as finish/error-handlers
            const sql = "INSERT INTO seller_portfolio_item (iduser, title, description) VALUES (?,?,?)";
            con.execute(sql, [iduser, title, description], function (err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err.toString());

                    if (err.toString().indexOf('cannot be null') >= 0) {
                        var response = errorCodes.not_null_parameters;
                        callback(null, response);
                    }
                    var response = errorCodes.internal_server_error;
                    callback(null, response);

                }
                else {
                    var response = {
                        "statusCode": 200,
                        "headers": {
                            "Content-Type": "application/json"
                        },
                        "body": JSON.stringify({ insertId: result.insertId }),
                        "isBase64Encoded": false
                    };
                    callback(null, response)
                }
            });
        }


    }
};
```

My code is capable of inserting just one record, not suitable to save multiple when I am sending a list. As a result, client program will have to call the same method again and again in a loop.

How can I read the list and insert multiple records ?

Comment: You could use a SQL string with multiple values: `"INSERT INTO seller_portfolio_item (iduser, title, description) VALUES (?,?,?), (?,?,?), (?,?,?)"`

Comment: I can't test it right now but because `mysql2` aims to be a drop-in replacement for `mysql` it might be that [How do I do a bulk insert in mySQL using node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899802/how-do-i-do-a-bulk-insert-in-mysql-using-node-js/56241509) works.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that going forward it is better to use `mysql` instead of `mysql2`. Below is one approach that can be used to batch insert multiple records.

Be sure to run `npm install mysql --save` to ensure you have to necessary package installed.

Working with multiple records requires some additional thinking and planning as well. You should consider:

- does your table contain any unique keys other than the primary?
- is it possible your API function will ever attempt to insert a duplicate?
- in the event of a duplicate how should it be handled?
- do you need to know the insert ID for every new record created?
- will every object in your list always have the same number of entries, the same keys, and expected values?

Depending on your answers to the above considerations the example I provided below would require additional code and complications. This example is the simplest implementation of the idea.

```js
// package changed, remember to npm install…
const mysql = require('mysql');

const errorCodes = require('source/error-codes');
const PropertiesReader = require('properties-reader');

const prop = PropertiesReader('properties.properties');

const con = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit: 10,
  host: prop.get('server.host') || '127.0.0.1',
  user: prop.get("server.username") || 'local_user',
  password: prop.get("server.password") || 'local_password',
  database: prop.get("server.dbname") || 'local_database',
  multipleStatements: true, // necessary to run chained queries
  charset: 'utf8mb4' // necessary if you might need support for emoji characters - table charset must match
});

exports.saveSellerPortfolioItem = (event, context, callback) => {
  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;

  // It is better to check for the existence of your
  // expected request body in the controller stage of
  // your app but I've included this for consistency
  // with your original code.
  let query_object = event.body ? JSON.parse(event.body) : null;
  console.log('query_object', query_object);
  if (!query_object.length) {
    let response = errorCodes.missing_parameters;
    callback(null, response)
  }

  else {
    // use the keys of the first object to define the field names.
    // you don't have to use this approach but it provides flexibility
    // if you will not always use the same fields
    let keys = Object.keys(query_object[0]);
    // map the values into a supported format
    let values = query_object.map( obj => keys.map( key => obj[key]));
    let sql = 'INSERT INTO seller_portfolio_item (' + keys.join(',') + ') ?;'
    con.query(sql, values, function(error, results, fields) {
      if (error) callback(null, error);

      // when inserting multiples you will only get back the
      // insert id of the first record. if there are updates
      // due to duplicate keys, you won't even get that.
      // results will look like this:
      console.log(results);
      // Expected output
      // OkPacket {
      //   fieldCount: 0,
      //   affectedRows: 3,
      //   insertId: 1,
      //   serverStatus: 2,
      //   warningCount: 6,
      //   message: '&Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 6',
      //   protocol41: true,
      //   changedRows: 0
      // }

      let response = {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "headers": {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "body": JSON.stringify({ records_inserted: results.affectedRows }),
        "isBase64Encoded": false
      };
      callback(null, response)
    });
  }
};
```