# Can not write data into mySql from node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

Before I have made a test run and Everything was ok, but know when I am trying to insert a new static data it is saying that result is undefined.
How to solve this?
[image: error from terminal]

```
const mysql = require("mysql")
const con = mysql.createConnection({
    host:"localhost",
    user:"root",
    password:"",
    database:"magebitdb"
});

con.connect((err)=>{
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log("connected to DB");
    

    // const sql =`INSERT INTO subscribers(email) VALUES (${email})`;
    const sqlInsert = ("INSERT INTO subscribers(email) VALUES ?")
    const values=[
        "test value"
    ]
    con.query(sqlInsert,[values],(err,result)=>{
        console.log(`inserted data is: ${result}`);
        console.log(values);
    });
});
```

Comment: `values` is already an array, you don't need to put it in another array with `[values]`

Comment: Not sure if inserting `[[values]]` is normal? Shouldn't it be `[values]` ?

Comment: @Barmar same error comes up

Comment: There's probably an error, you should check if `err` is set and print that.

Comment: `if (err) throw err;`

Comment: Actually, you need another level of array nesting. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899802/how-do-i-do-a-bulk-insert-in-mysql-using-node-js

Comment: @Barmar it is not about array, the way that I wrote in code is correct. It does not affect to the result.

Comment: @Barmar this is the sql error statement: sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''test value'' at line 1",

Comment: If it didn't affect the result you wouldn't be getting that error. Change it to `[[values]]` and it should work, or change `values` to a 2-dimensional array.

Comment: @Barmar thank you for the help. I have found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution for this error.

I have console logged `err` in `con.query` and I noticed that in error there was no brackets and it was causing an error in the SQL syntax.

Basically I added brackets to `sqlInsert` and it worked
`const sqlInsert = ("INSERT INTO subscribers(email) VALUES (?)")`