# Bulk insert in mySQL using node.js not working

Tags: mysql, node.js, insert, bulk

Referring to this thread [How do I do a bulk insert in mySQL using node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899802/how-do-i-do-a-bulk-insert-in-mysql-using-node-js) I have written the below code

```
const values = [
    ['e33b3c34923500e6', 'The Office', '330248b39a55d82a', '690db8528741c098'], 
    ['e33b3c34923500e7', 'Prison Break', '330248b39a55d82a', '690db8528741c098']
]

let sql = `INSERT INTO Result (resultId, result, submissionId, questionId) VALUES ?`


connection.query(sql, [values], (err, res) => {console.log(err)
console.log(res)
})
```

Normal single inserts work with the given values but whenever trying to bulk insert like above I get the following error:

`return await usedQueryRunner.query(query, parameters);  // await is needed here because we are using finally TypeError: usedQueryRunner.query is not a function`